# React TypeScript error unless I spread props

Tags: typescript

I get a TypeScript error for the following React code, unless I spread the props. Why is this happening?

```
interface SString {
  type: "str1" | "str2";
  value: { valueLiteral: string };
}

interface SNumeric {
  type: "num1" | "num2";
  value: { valueLiteral: number };
}

type Section = SString | SNumeric;

interface State {
  sections: Section[];
}

const state: State = {
  sections: [
    { type: "str1", value: { valueLiteral: "val1" } },
    { type: "num1", value: { valueLiteral: 1 } }
  ]
};

function Comp({ type, value }: Section) {
  return (
    <div style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
      <div>{type}</div>
      <div>{value.valueLiteral}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.sections.map((item) => {
        // return <Comp key={item.type} {...item} />; // This doesnt error
        return <Comp key={item.type} type={item.type} value={item.value} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> function Comp({ type, value }: Section): JSX.Element Type '{ key:
> "str1" | "str2" | "num1" | "num2"; type: "str1" | "str2" | "num1" |
> "num2"; value: { valueLiteral: string; } | { valueLiteral: number; };
> }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Section'.   Type
> '{ key: "str1" | "str2" | "num1" | "num2"; type: "str1" | "str2" |
> "num1" | "num2"; value: { valueLiteral: string; } | { valueLiteral:
> number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SNumeric'.
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type '"str1" | "str2" | "num1" | "num2"' is not assignable to type '"num1" | "num2"'.
> Type '"str1"' is not assignable to type '"num1" | "num2"'.ts(2322)
>
> Blockquote

UPDATE: The code above was simplified but maybe its not clear what Im trying to achieve.

I have an array of objects of type `ValCord`, `ValString` and `ValNumeric`. I need to pass these to a React component and have that component call other components depending on the object type.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-sunset-8egckr?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1594

```
interface ValCord {
  type: "padding" | "margin";
  value: { x: number; y: number };
}
interface ValString {
  type: "color" | "font";
  value: string;
}
interface ValNumeric {
  type: "font-size" | "font-weight";
  value: number;
}
type Val = ValCord | ValString | ValNumeric;
interface State {
  sections: Val[];
}

const val1: ValCord = {
  type: "padding",
  value: {
    y: 8,
    x: 10
  }
};
const val2: ValString = {
  type: "color",
  value: "white"
};
const val3: ValNumeric = {
  type: "font-size",
  value: 12
};
const state: State = {
  sections: [val1, val2, val3]
};

function ValCordComp({ type, value }: ValCord) {
  return (
    <div>
      {type} - X:{value.x} Y:{value.y}
    </div>
  );
}
function ValStringComp({ type, value }: ValString) {
  return (
    <div>
      {type} is {value.toUpperCase()}
    </div>
  );
}
function ValNumericComp({ type, value }: ValNumeric) {
  return (
    <div>
      {type} is {value * 100}
    </div>
  );
}
function Comp({ type, value }: Val) {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
      {type === "padding" ? <ValCordComp type={type} value={value} /> : null}
      {type === "color" ? <ValStringComp type={type} value={value} /> : null}
      {type === "font-size" ? (
        <ValNumericComp type={type} value={value} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.sections.map((item) => {
        // return <Comp key={item.type} {...item} />;
        return <Comp key={item.type} type={item.type} value={item.value} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that the object you are passing as props to the Comp function is not assignable to the Section interface. Specifically, the error message is saying that the type property of the passed object is not compatible with the expected type property of the SNumeric type.

Comment: This is because the type property of the passed object can be either "str1" | "str2" | "num1" | "num2", but the type property of the SNumeric type can only be "num1" | "num2". Therefore, TypeScript is correctly throwing an error because the type property of the passed object cannot be "str1" when the SNumeric type is expected.

Comment: To fix this error, you can ensure that the type property of the passed object is either "num1" or "num2" when passing it as a SNumeric object to the Comp function.

Comment: @NoorFahad With 3 sizable comments covering the issue + solution, this would really be better posted as an answer.

Comment: I need to allow Comp to accept either SString or SNumeric. Is there a different approach that could achieve this?

Comment: @NoorFahad Ive updated my question with a more detailed code example.

Comment: @Evanss I Will check, the answer given below is working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, the type of the `type` prop when you pass it to `Comp` is `"str1" | "str2" | "num1" | "num2"` which is too wide and Typescript complains that this is neither SNumeric nor SString.

My suggestion to get around this is to pass the entire section as a prop so that you don't lose this information:

```
function Comp({ section }: { section: Section }) {
  return (
    <div style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
      <div>{section.type}</div>
      <div>{section.value.valueLiteral}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.sections.map((item) => {
        return <Comp key={item.type} section={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```